Trying to Turn Off TOC Subsection Page Numbers with \titletoc Application
This post is related to Delineating TOC Subsection Entries Horizontally (Instead of Vertically).
Based on Werner's excellent answer found here: How do I get multiple ToC entries in the same line?, I have modified my previous code to:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=red,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=red
}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{3pt}} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip 5pt}  


\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [3.5em]
  {\large}
  {}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\ \thecontentspage}% <filler-page-format>
  [\ ]% <separator>
  %[,\hskip 3pt\ ]% <separator>
  []% <end>
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% Display up to \subsection in ToC


\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\section*{JANUARY}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{JANUARY}

\subsection*{January 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 1}

\subsection*{January 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 2}

\subsection*{January 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 3}

\subsection*{January 4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 4}

\subsection*{January 5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 5}

\subsection*{January 6}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 6}

\subsection*{January 7}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 7}

\subsection*{January 8}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 8}

\subsection*{January 9}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 9}

\subsection*{January 10}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 10}

\subsection*{January 11}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 11}

\subsection*{January 12}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 12}


\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}

and which produces the TOC:

QUESTION UPDATE: \cftpagenumbersoff{subsection} is not turning off the TOC subsection page numbers. A posted comment has indicated that tocloft and titletoc are incompatible. How may I keep the horizontal delineation of subsection entries while eliminating the associated page numbers? My attempts so far have been unsuccessful.
Thank you.

Why would you expect that tocloft and titletoc are compatible? Titletoc completely overwrites whatever tocloft set up. Use only one of them.

The starred version of \titlecontents is used for setting content entries within a paragraph style and has the following form:
\titlecontents*{<section>}
  [<left>]
  {<above-code>}
  {<numbered-entry-format>}
  {<numberless-entry-format>}
  {<filler-page-format>}
  [<separator>]

You need to remove the <filler-page-format>, which sets the page number. So, for example:
\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [1em]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {}% <filler-page-format>
  [\ \ ]% <separator>



Many thanks once again for your most helpful answer.
